# Can Linux support Mirror Bootable Disk with LVM like IBM-AIX/HP/Solaris UNIX?

Tags: linux, boot, mirror

I have searched a lot in Google and Linux sites, but it seems that only UNIX, especially HP-UX supports mirror bootable disk configuration.

Can anyone tell me whether Linux (I am using SuSE 10) can support this or not, and how to if can?

I have found one shell scripts of HP-UNIX config about this, please see [here](http://linuxshellaccount.blogspot.com/2008/10/lvms-roots-mirroring-your-boot-disk-on.html)

Comment: What is "mirror bootable disk configuration"? Please edit your question and add this.

Comment: this sounds like a raid1 setup - yes it is possible.

Comment: I have added one sample configured on HP-UNIX, please kindly see the edited question, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  This is why it is recommended to install the grub MBR into all drives of an mdadm raid array - if one drive dies you'll still be able to boot....depending on your BIOS you may have to change the boot device or it may auto-detect.

Grub2 is capable of booting linux from all common linux filesystem types on LVM and mdadm software raid devices - whether used separately or in combination.

Many people keep a RAID-1 ext2 /boot partition for this purpose just to keep things simple (and out of habit from when it was required if your setup was even slightly unusual), but it's not strictly necessary these days.

Comment: When it comes to mirroring (aka RAID 1) I would really recommend to use mdadm+LVM on top, rather than using LVM mirroring options. It is a much more widely used setup, hence more stable.

Comment: @huygens, yes agreed. mdadm for the raid, LVM for the volume management

Comment: I just learned the hard way that GRUB can't boot from LVM mirrored boot partition.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose besides the LVM partition you always need a "normal" partition on at least one harddrive, where grub, a kernel and an initrd may live, so that grub can load kernel and initrd. The initrd can then boot into the LVM-root partition. You can find instructions [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1664&page=3) and a little [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/creating-initrd-to-boot-from-lvm-452959/).

Comment: Grub2 can cope with LVM just fine. Any bootloader can cope with a RAID-1 boot partition by the simple expedient of ignoring one of the copies, though that only works for total disk failures, not for partial failures.

Comment: Grub2 can handle LVM only after it has loaded the respective modules which tend to reside on a filesystem on a partition on a harddrive. Your ignorant view on hard disks works exactly for raid1 and will not work for raid10 and will not work if the LVM volume does not start at exactly the partition/harddrive boundaries. A lot of assumptions there ...